# Simplest way to deploy including configurations of managed package items

Tags: managed-package, deployment

I started created a changeset and discovered that it seems they can't contain changes made on managed packages (screen layouts, validation rules, pick list items...).

What's the simplest alternative I can use that can deal with these?

I didn't like the sound of a command-line tool like the Force.com Migration Tool, but I'm not fond of Eclipse either, so what I like may not matter.  I just want to do my first deploy;  I don't have days to spend figuring out how to do it.

P.S.  I have written many scripts in many different languages and worked with many configuration management systems, but have no experience with ANT.  I also have IntelliJ with the Illuminated Cloud plug-in, but do not have a project that includes everything and wasn't sure it was a good idea to do my first deploy with a sophisticated tool.

Comment: I looked through the available metadata and it doesn't seem there is anything relevant.  I have inquired with the managed package vendor as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my changes to the managed package configuration would probably only take 4-5 hours to simply do over, I'm guessing my best option is to redo them by hand in the production org, and use some simple mechanisms like changesets or an IDE to deploy the Apex and triggers.

Upvote this if you feel it's the best option, and I'll do it if it wins.

Comment: This was what I did, and it worked better than I expected.  In my case it ended up taking me less than an hour to replicate the configuration changes in production.
Also, the managed package vendor I talked to confirmed that they do not know any way to do this other than manually repeating the changes as I did.